# Using custom expression when relating tables in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, relationship, ssas-2012

In SSAS (Tabular model), I have 2 tables.

```
Student                      Grade
+-----------+-------+        +----------+--------+---------+
| StudentId | Score |        |  Title   | LowEnd | HighEnd |
+-----------+-------+        +----------+--------+---------+
|         1 |    70 |        | Intermed |     60 |      74 |
|         2 |    80 |        | Good     |     75 |      89 |
|         3 |    92 |        | Excelent |     90 |     100 |
+-----------+-------+        +----------+--------+---------+
```

I want to relate `Student` table to `Grade` table, but there is no direct relation (FK), because I want to related tables using the `LowEnd` and `HighEnd` value in `Grade` table

In query representation, my desired join will be this:

```
select St.StudentId, Gr.Title
from Student St 
  inner join Grade Gr on St.Score between Gr.LowEnd and Gr.HighEnd
```

**The question is: Is there any way to make such a relation in SSAS?**

Comment: Best way is to change the Grade table to have one row per grade. So Intermed would have 14 rows. Then the join is simple.

Comment: @GregGalloway, Good idea. If there was not better answer, I might go this way. Thanks